# Search in a perimeter according to another perimeter

Tags: php, sql, geolocation, radius

Recently I needed to look for all the people close to my position. My position was nuanced by a perimeter. For example all the people in the 5km around me.

For this: no problem, after some research and various modifications I had the function.

Here is the current function that works **perfectly**:

```
$lat = $latMe; // My latitude
$lon = $lonMe; // My longitude
$rad = $distancePeople; // My perimeter like 10km

$R = 6371; // Earth rayon

$maxLat = $lat + rad2deg($rad/$R);
$minLat = $lat - rad2deg($rad/$R);
$maxlon = $lon + rad2deg(asin($rad/$R) / cos(deg2rad($lat)));
$minlon = $lon - rad2deg(asin($rad/$R) / cos(deg2rad($lat)));

$sql = "SELECT *, acos(sin(:lat)*sin(radians(lati)) + cos(:lat)*cos(radians(lati))*cos(radians(longi)-:lon)) * :R As D
        FROM ( SELECT * FROM people WHERE lati Between :minLat And :maxLat And longi Between :minlon And :maxlon ) As FirstCut
        WHERE acos(sin(:lat)*sin(radians(lati)) + cos(:lat)*cos(radians(lati))*cos(radians(longi)-:lon)) * :R < :rad ORDER by date";

$params = [
    'lat'    => deg2rad($lat),
    'lon'    => deg2rad($lon),
    'minLat' => $minLat,
    'minlon' => $minlon,
    'maxLat' => $maxLat,
    'maxlon' => $maxlon,
    'rad'    => $rad,
    'R'      => $R,
];
```

Today I need more complex and I can not find ... (**in PHP**)

I need to find around me, in a given area, the people who themselves have stipulated a scope of "availability".

For example I say that I can move from my position and in the 10km around and people say the same thing, so I need to search around me at 10km points available themselves within a radius of 10km .. .. Yes a little complicated to explain in writing.

Basically, schematically, one will have my circle and full of circles (the other people) and it is necessary that I find the people whose circle passes in mine. (yes it is the maternal explanation)

Thanks in advance !

[image: How it have to work - In green the good section, two people selectionned]

Comment: This is really a nice question bit hard to explain in text but the image explains very well